# selenium webdriver not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium version: 2.53.6
Firefox version: 47.0.1
Chrome version: 51.0.2704.106 m

Now if I want to use them like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
```

i get an error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]

i even checked the manual twice that its the correct way to code it.

So why cant it find the browsers even though everything is updated to latest version?
Firefox and chrome work fine if I use them as person.

edit:
can provide error code in comment so here it is, (srry some parts are in german, as it is the main language istalled on my pc):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\extension_connection.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 67, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py", line 90, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

and for Chrome its:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1224, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

the wierd thing is i did include it in path enivornment variables. I can type in 'chromedriver' in the cmd and it finds it.... so python should too.
1 more mistake:
doing last thing says some wierd stuff about: only local connetctions are allowed.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error? Probably you are missing the chrome  driver.

Comment: Bump, as I still can't get it to work at all

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about running two drivers at the same time, but for the chrome part at least you may need to point it to a chrome driver (which you can download from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\..\..\chromedriver.exe')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path that script is running in.
driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:\AutomatedTesting\PyTestFramework\Automation\selenium\AdditionalDrivers\chromedriver.exe') #this is my path, I haven't worked out how to make the path relative to the script yet
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```